# Hadoop archive file cannot be looked up using hadoop fs -ls har://hdfs-master/tank/zoo.har/

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

here is my files on hdfs:

```
hadoop fs -ls /
Found 5 items
-rw-r--r--   3 hadoop supergroup         25 2016-04-18 11:29 /abc.txt
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2016-04-17 11:39 /hbase
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2016-04-18 11:49 /tank
drwx------   - hadoop supergroup          0 2016-04-18 11:30 /tmp
-rw-r--r--   3 hadoop supergroup         66 2016-04-18 11:29 /user.txt

hadoop fs -ls /tank/

Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2016-04-18 11:49 /tank/zoo.har
```

while l am typing

> hadoop fs -ls har://hdfs-master/zoo.har/
>
> Blockquote

that got response:

> ls: Invalid path for the Har Filesystem. No index file in
>   har://hdfs-master/zoo.har

please help me out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there are two format to access these files or directories:

First one as following:
`hadoop fs -lsr har:///tank/zoo.har/`

The other:
`hadoop fs -lsr har://hdfs-master/tank/zoo.har/`

By the way, are you sure your host is `master` and the HDFS daemon is listening on default port? Cause second format means `har://hdfs-host:port/path/to/somewhere`.

Comment: l have tried what you said before but still the same, by the way, my cluster consists of one namenode with hostname of master and four datanodes

Comment: Sorry for not specifying the difference between our commands. But congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add my parent path to the har url，it should be har:///parent-path/har-path!